# shared image not getting changed itself on facebook when it gets changed to path

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am sharing the following URL : http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/share.php

share link : http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/index.php

So it shares "http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/3.jpg" this image on facebook wall.

Now I am replacing `anyother.jpg` with `3.jpg` on the same path. It is not get changed on facebook as well as it is not get changed facebook debugger.

Can Anyone knows, why this issue happens ? Any one faced this issue before.

I have used `og tag` for image sharing.

Same issue with twitter and Instagram also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook create the cache of URL. So you are seeing old cache image from old page. Change the URL of image & page too and try again.

Change the URL

```
http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/share.php
http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/3.jpg
```

To

```
http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/share1.php
http://ebiztrait.co.uk/demo/demo/3-1.jpg
```